# C# Console Auto Reconnect Server to Client

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

Hello Could anybody help me about this  I'm trying to create client and server application reverse connection. When I tried to open the client and server I didn't encounter any problem vise versa. The scenario is I execute the client and the server but when I closed the server and re open again it doesn't accept any connection both connection lost.

Here is the Code:

CLIENT CODE:

```
namespace client1
{
  class Program
   {
    public static bool isConnected { get; set; }
    public static NetworkStream Writer { get; set; }
    public static NetworkStream Reciever { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Connect_To_Server();
    }

    public static void Connect_To_Server()
    {
        TcpClient Connecting = new TcpClient();
        string IP = "178.121.1.2";
        while (isConnected == false)
        {
            try
            {
                Connecting.Connect(IP, 2000);
                isConnected = true;

                Writer = Connecting.GetStream();
                Reciever = Connecting.GetStream();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected: " + IP);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error Connection... .");
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

 }
}
```

SERVER CODE:

```
 namespace server1
 {
  class Program
   {

    public static bool isConnected { get; set; }
    public static NetworkStream Writer { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Listen_To_Client();
    }

    public static void Listen_To_Client()
    {
        TcpListener Listen = new TcpListener(2000);

        while (true)
        {
            Listen.Start();

            if (Listen.Pending())
            {

                TcpClient Connect = Listen.AcceptTcpClient();
                isConnected = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Accepted");
                Writer = Connect.GetStream();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

      }

     }
    }
```

Comment: I don't get it , your client invokes once , so how do you expect to execute twice , Am i missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstood. I just run the client once but for the server I want to run it multiple times. If i close my server once then re open again my client  and server does not communicate anymore. It's been days figuring this still no luck. I'm new in socket programming.

Comment: The issue here is you connect once to the server. Then you close that connection. Afterwards you need to establish a new connection to the server (i.e. calling `Connect_To_Server()` again).

Comment: Sir any example code how to establish new connection in my code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a local variable `isConnected` you should check for `Connecting.Connected`.
In your case you connect once and set `isConnected` to `true`. Now your `while` loop condition ends up as `false` and you never try to reconnect your client.

Edit:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
        if (client.Connected)
        {
            // do something
            client.close();
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException) { }

    Thread.Sleep(millisecs);
}
```

Bare in mind that you should not run this loop in your GUI thread since it has all sorts of blocking potential. Also only try to connect if you want to interact with the server. But for now this code should work for you.

Comment: I don't know how to figure out I'm just using while loop and .Connected? Still not working

while (Connecting.Connected == false)
{
.... .
}

Comment: @user2528270 I put some code into my answer. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much nuke! works perfect! god bless you. Could you recommend me a book that will help me as a beginner in socket programming? I'm a asp.net web dev and new in socket programming.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Unfortunately I don't have a book title I could recommend to you, but there should be plenty tutorials on the web.